# Subtracting until 0, but the subtraction impossible to reach 0

Tags: python, oop

i wanted to make the calculation stop on zero (self.health == 0), but it keeps subtract until below the zero. the subtraction is impossible to reach 0. How do i make the calculation, so the code doesn't reach the negative numbers?

```
class Hero:
    def __init__(self, name, health, damage, armor, m_speed):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.damage = damage
        self.armor = armor
        self.m_speed = m_speed
    def attack(self, enemy):
        print(self.name + " has attacked " + enemy.name)
        enemy.attacked(self, self.damage)
    def attacked(self, enemy, damage_enemy):
        print(self.name + " has been attacked by " + enemy.name)
        attack_received = (damage_enemy/(2.5*self.armor))
        print(str(attack_received) + " is taken")
        self.health -= attack_received
        print(self.name + " health is now " + str(self.health))
    def dead(self, enemy):
        while self.health > 0:
            h1.attack(h2)
            print("\n")
            h2.attack(h1)
            print("\n")
            if self.health == 0:
                break
h1 = Hero("Hero1", 532, 129, 5, 310)
h2 = Hero("Hero2", 476, 176, 4, 296)
h1.dead(h2)
print("\n")
h2.dead(h1)
```

Comment: Your loop breaks if and only if health == 0. Maybe you just have to change the break condition to `if self.health <= 0:`

Comment: In the `dead` method, `h1` and `h2` should probably be `self` and `enemy` (or the other way around).  And I would test for `health <= 0`, in case I have 1hp and get hit with 5 damage.

Answer (score 0):

Define a method `alive` (maybe worth defining as a property if you are familiar with it):

```py
    def alive(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            return True
        return False
```

You had `h1` and `h2` inside the `dead` method, you wanted to refer to `self` and `enemy`.
Change the `dead` method to something like this (`dead` is a bad name, use something else):

```py
    def combat(self, enemy):
        while enemy.alive() and self.alive():
            if enemy.alive():
                enemy.attack(self) 
            if self.alive():
                self.attack(enemy)
            print("\n")
```

Also worth putting

```py
    if not self.alive():
        print(self.name + " is dead.")
```

to the end of `attacked` method. There are more things to improve, but I think this should be enough to get you started.